# Symfony create entity ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity skill and language who have relationship ManyToMany.

I create skill and select language I see this in my table many to many id skill and id language, but when I create language and select skill I don't have new row in table skill_language, but after flush I have:

```
$afetr_skills = $entity->getSkills()->getValues();
```

have skill, but I don't see this in table in DB. What I'm doing wrong? Help please.

My entity:

```
class CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="languages", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $languages;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Skill", mappedBy="language", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $skills;
```

and skill:

```
class Skill
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="skill", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $skill;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $language;
```

and form to add language:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('languages',  'text', array('label' => 'Skill Name'));

            $builder->add('skills','entity',
                array(
                    'class'=>'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Skill',
                    'property'=>'skill',
                    'multiple'=>true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                     )
            );

    $builder
    ->add('save','submit')
    ;
}
```

and my action:

```
    public function newLanguageAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = new CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages();
    $form = $this->createForm(new LanguageType(), $entity);
    $form->submit($request);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
            $skills = $entity->getSkills()->getValues();

            if(!empty($skills)){
                foreach($skills as $skill){
                    $skill->removeLanguage($entity);
                    $em->persist($skill);
                    $em->flush();
                }
            }

            if(!empty($form_skills)){
                foreach($form_skills as $skill){
                    $skill->addLanguage($entity);
                    $em->persist($skill);
                    $em->flush();
                }
            }
        }
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('languages_show'));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'debug' => true,
        'form'      => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

When I edit entity I first remove all skill and then add skill by form, but I know this is bad away. 
 How in doctrine use this relationship and set in DB ?